# How to create effect same video with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How to make a video from an image with a drag effect like this one in FFmpeg:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zC6qbpe3FyE&ab_channel=CloudMood
```

I tried to zoom in zoom out effects but not the same with video

```
 ffmpeg -loop 1 -i photo.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.001,1.2)':x='if(gte(zoom,1.2),x+2,x-1)':y='if(gte(zoom,1.2),y+2,y-1)':d=10*25,framerate=25,scale=1920:1080" -c:v libx264 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1080 output.mp4
```

Comment: Are you referring to the fade in effect at the very start?  Filters require frames enough to facilitate the effect.  You would have to generate enough frames to make the effect, but then you won't have a still image.  So it will close when the video stream ends.  I think the only way to do this is pre-animate your image to .gif or .apng (without infinite looping) before ffmpeg processing.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any other library to do this animation?

Comment: try crop: `crop=iw*7/8:ih*7/8:(iw-ow)/2+((iw-ow)/8)*sin(n/12):(ih-oh)/2 +((ih-oh)/8)*sin(n/16)`, change digits for yours